# sqlite3.OperationalError: foreign key mismatch ent python

Tags: python, sqlite

Buenos dias estoy tratando de referencias el nombre de una pelicula dentro de mi tabla SALAS para poderla mostrar despues en mi programa el unico detalle que me esta marcando este error.

```
"conn.execute("INSERT INTO SALAS(ID,NUM_SALA,ID_CUIDADES,ID_ESTADOS,ID_HORARIO,ID_FECHA,NOMBRE_PELICULA) VALUES (1,1,'AS','S11','10:45AM',2/08/2022,'Avengers')");
sqlite3.OperationalError: foreign key mismatch - "SALAS" referencing "PELICULAS""
```

El querry de la base de datos es la siguiente:

```
import sqlite3

# Define connection and cursor
connection = sqlite3.connect('cinemaaaaaaaa.db')


query =(""" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ESTADOS
    ( ID    TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
      NOMBRE_ESTADO  TEXT NOT NULL
    );""")
connection.execute(query)

query =(""" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CUIDADES 
    ( ID    TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
      NOMBRE_CUIDADES  TEXT NOT NULL,
      ID_ESTADO TEXT NOT NULL,
      FOREIGN KEY (ID_ESTADO) REFERENCES ESTADOS(ID)
    );""")
connection.execute(query)


query =(""" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PELICULAS
    ( ID    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
      NOMBRE  TEXT NOT NULL,
      DIRECTOR TEXT NOT NULL,
      CATEGORIA   TEXT NOT NULL,
      DURACION   TIME NOT NULL,
      GENERO TEXT NOT NULL,
      ID_CUIDADES TEXT NOT NULL,
      ID_ESTADOS TEXT NOT NULL,
      FOREIGN KEY (ID_CUIDADES) REFERENCES CUIDADES(ID)
      FOREIGN KEY (ID_ESTADOS) REFERENCES ESTADOS(ID)
    );""")
connection.execute(query)

query =(""" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS HORARIOS
    ( ID    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
      FECHA DATE NOT NULL,
      HORARIO TIME_STRING NOT NULL,
      ID_CUIDADES TEXT NOT NULL,
      ID_ESTADOS TEXT NOT NULL,
      ID_PELICULA INTEGER NOT NULL,
      FOREIGN KEY (ID_CUIDADES) REFERENCES CUIDADES(ID)
      FOREIGN KEY (ID_ESTADOS) REFERENCES ESTADOS(ID)
      FOREIGN KEY (ID_PELICULA) REFERENCES PELICULAS(ID)
    );""")
connection.execute(query)

query =(""" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SALAS
    ( ID    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
      NUM_SALA  INTEGER NOT NULL,
      ID_CUIDADES TEXT NOT NULL,
      ID_ESTADOS TEXT NOT NULL,
      ID_HORARIO TIME_STRING NOT NULL,
      ID_FECHA DATE NOT NULL,
      ID_PELICULA INTEGER NOT NULL,
      NOMBRE_PELICULA TEXT NOT NULL,
      FOREIGN KEY (ID_CUIDADES) REFERENCES CUIDADES(ID)
      FOREIGN KEY (ID_ESTADOS) REFERENCES ESTADOS(ID)
      FOREIGN KEY (ID_FECHA) REFERENCES HORARIOS(FECHA)
      FOREIGN KEY (ID_PELICULA) REFERENCES PELICULAS(ID)
      FOREIGN KEY (ID_HORARIO) REFERENCES HORARIOS(HORARIO)
      FOREIGN KEY (NOMBRE_PELICULA) REFERENCES PELICULAS(NOMBRE)
    );""")
connection.execute(query)
connection.close()
```

El querry que estoy ejecutando para poder insertar es el siguiente:

```
    import  sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('cinemaaaaaaaa.db')

conn.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON")


#conn.execute("INSERT INTO CUIDADES(ID,NOMBRE_CUIDADES,ID_ESTADO) VALUES ('AS','Guasave','S11')");
#conn.execute("INSERT INTO ESTADOS(ID,NOMBRE_ESTADO) VALUES ('S11','SINALOA')");

#conn.execute("INSERT INTO PELICULAS(ID,NOMBRE,DIRECTOR,CATEGORIA,DURACION,GENERO,ID_CUIDADES,ID_ESTADOS) VALUES (1,'Avengers', 'Steven Spilverg', 'Teen',120,'Accion','AS','S11')");
#conn.execute("INSERT INTO HORARIOS(ID,FECHA,HORARIO,ID_ESTADOS,ID_CUIDADES,ID_PELICULA) VALUES (1,'2/08/2022','10:45AM','S11','AS',1)");
```

----Esta es la parte que me esta dando problemas y muestra el error que previamente les comente -----

```
    conn.execute("INSERT INTO 
SALAS(ID,NUM_SALA,ID_CUIDADES,ID_ESTADOS,ID_HORARIO,ID_FECHA,NOMBRE_PELICULA) VALUES (1,1,'AS','S11','10:45AM',2/08/2022,1,'Avengers')");
    conn.commit()
```

Algunas cosas estan comentadas para poder revisar que los datos se estan ingresando correctamente
------- cualquier ayuda sera bienvenida y muchas gracias.-------

Comment: Detalles.. todos los id de las tablas deberian ser autonumericos. si no, cuando quieras ingresar el siguiente, vas a tener que pedirle a la base cual es el ultimo, y en un entorno multiusuarios, eso implica bloqueos y puede provocar fallos. Dicho esto, salvo que estes en otra base de datos, el query deberia funcionar... Probaste hacer un select a la tabla de peliculas a ver si existe? de paso, usa nombres que puedas reonocer.. un archivo que se llama cinemaaaaaaa (con muchas a) es muy propenso a errores.. que pasa si tenes una a de menos o mas?

Comment: Se que tiene sus detalles pero este proyecto es para la escuela, pero tienes toda la razon una buena practica no esta de mas, la tabla existe el unico detalle es lo que ando preguntando cuando lo ejecuto aparece ese error. y la base de datos si es la correcta verifique eso

Comment: que la tabla exista, no quiere decir que tenga los datos que necesitas.. estas seguro que los tiene?

Comment: Si tiene todo los datos que se necesitan, dentro de la tabla de pelicuas

Comment: Y la base, esta grabada? suena a que no estan.. si pobras el insert directo en la db funciona?

Comment: Si esta grabada y pude ingresar todo los datos anteriores solo me marca error en la parte que mencione

Comment: @Christian esta dentro de la cadena.. lo manda asi como esta.. ademas el error le dice que es de integridad referencial.. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recomiendo leer y practicar un poco más SQL. El problema no es Python, si no en la Base de Datos y es que no estás respetando el [modelo entidad relación](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+entidad+relacion).

```
> INSERT INTO CUIDADES(ID,NOMBRE_CUIDADES,ID_ESTADO) VALUES ('AS','Guasave','S11');
Error while executing SQL query on database: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

Las llaves foráneas no te van a dejar crear un registro si no tienes otros registros dependientes, esto como manera de preservar la integridad de la data.
Este es el diagrama de la BD (Se usó DBVisualizer para generarlo)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedes notar, para poder crear una **Ciudad**, necesitas primero crear un **Estado**:

```
> INSERT INTO ESTADOS(ID,NOMBRE_ESTADO) VALUES ('S11','SINALOA');
Rows affected: 1
```

Y ahora si, se puede crear la ciudad:

```
> INSERT INTO CUIDADES(ID,NOMBRE_CUIDADES,ID_ESTADO) VALUES ('AS','Guasave','S11');
Rows affected: 1
```

Lo mismo va a pasar en las demás tablas. Finalmente para poder crear una Sala, te va a pedir al menos un dato relacionado en todas las demás tablas. Verifica que esa base de datos esté correctamente diseñada.

Por otro lado, [sigue estándares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) y guarda las fechas en formato YYYY-MM-DD. No vas a poder hacer cálculos con fechas si están en otro formato.

Comment: Gracias por la clarificacion el detalle que ya tenia las tablas creadas previamente, antes de ingresar los datos como mencionas es logico, lo que si pondre en cuenta es la parte del formato de la fecha eso si esta mal. Gracias por la respuesta tan Elaborada y explicativa.